# How to track temperature changes using sensors?

Tags: power-management

I have Ubuntu 13.10 with sensors installed. Everything works fine, but I'm wondering if I can somehow keep track of temperature changes. Nothing fancy - Max and Min would do. It would be even better if I could have a chart with temperature of each core recorded, but not necessary.

Any thoughts? Maybe using command line tool and making a script that would execute sensors command every 1 second and then store the output into a file? Sounds a bit bulky, but if nothing better is available, I guess it would do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Unity, psensor is included in Ubuntu since 12.04, it includes a graphic chart and apparently also register it. To install it in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

For further explanation and how to add the PPA which includes last available release:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/monitor-hardware-temperature-in-ubuntu.html

[image]

Comment: thx - that does the job :)